# Receiving submitted POST file Object in server side Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

When user sends a multi part form with files/images selected, generally in Meteor or node.js, the server side POST url handler uses this.request or req or request object to detect whether its a POST method or any other and its headers etc but what I don't understand is, where is the actually file located at this request object and how do I retrieve it so that it can be used for image/file upload or certain manipulations at server?

Answer (score 0):

node provides the **querystring** api to parse strings that look like:

```
foo=bar&baz=qux&baz=quux&corge
```

...which is how multi part form data is also sent. Parsing this with that api will return an object:

```
{ foo: 'bar', baz: ['qux', 'quux'], corge: '' }
```

So, you can first detect the method of the request, and if it is `POST`, you can attach a handler to `'data'`, get all the data into your own variable, and on `'end'` , parse it using `querystring`:

```
var qs = require('querystring');

// your request callback function would be something like:
function (request,response){
    if(request.method=='POST'){
        var body = '';
        request.on('data',function(data){
            body += data;

            //reject requests that have sent too much data (eg 2MB):
            if(body.length > 2e6){
                // Send HTTP status code for `Request Entity Too Large`:
                response.writeHead(413); 
                response.end();
        });
        request.on('end', function(){
             var form = qs.parse(body);
             //use form as object
        });
    } // end if
} // end handler
```